# PHP form adding recipent email

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send a simple email form, everything is working fine, however I keep receiving the recipient email at the end of the body message. I examined the PHP code but I couldn't find why is displaying that email again, here is the PHP code:

```
$name = $_POST['name']; 
$company = $_POST['company'];
$website = $_POST['website'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_from = 'juano.diy@gmail.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
"Company: $company.\n".
"Website: $website.\n".
"Contact Email: $visitor_email.\n".
"Here is the message:\n$message.\n".
"\n".                                                                                                                                                           

$to = "juano.diy@gmail.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

I'm introducing these details in the form:

```
Name: xxx
Company: xxx
website: www.xxx.com
email: xxx@live.com
message: Hi testing email
```

and this is what I am receiving:

```
You have received a new message from the user Juan Camilo. 
Company: Blitzar.
Website: www.stiktag.com.
Contact Email: juano.diy@live.com.
Here is the message:
Hi, testing website.

juano.diy@gmail.com
```

The problem is the last line (juano.diy@gmail.com), why am I receiving that address when I already added it to the header, I don't want to see it there, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last line of your `$email_body` is concatenating down.

`$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
"Company: $company.\n".
"Website: $website.\n".
"Contact Email: $visitor_email.\n".
"Here is the message:\n$message.\n".
"\n".`

Replace the last line: `"\n".` with `"\n";` - notice the semicolon. This terminates the assignment.